# Getting the Graph ID for a SharePoint document using the CSOM or REST api?

Tags: rest, csom, graph

If we are crawling sharepoint online, we can access these data from API using:

- MS graph API
  or
- SharePoint REST API (CSOM, ODATA)

All of our code uses the CSOM rest API for SharePoint.

But, for each list item in a list, we would like to get the Graph ID that corresponds to the List Item ID. That way, we store an ID that is compatible with the MS Graph API in case we want to look up that document there.

Do SharePoint list item fields available from the Rest APIs contain a field with the MS graph id for the list item?

UPDATE:

After some research, I believe I was using the incorrect terminology for "Graph ID." Sounds like the correct terminology is "OneDrive Item ID" and they look like this: `01JSWLMSD5CVNHFLHNDNGLWP2WGNNGDEG2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to get it. It's in fields on the SP.File object: `VroomItemID` and `VroomDriveID`.

```
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"></View>";
    ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(collListItem,
      listItems => listItems.Include(
          listItem => listItem.File.VroomItemID,
          listItem => listItem.File.VroomDriveID
        ));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of those properties on the SP.File object. Thank you for posting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "Graph ID". The item ID for a list item is the same regardless of the API.

Maybe this will help. If I access the item in the Documents library with the item ID equal 1 using this REST API request

`https://robwindsortest991.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items(1)`

Then I can access the same item using this Microsoft Graph request

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/robwindsortest991.sharepoint.com:/sites/Demo:/Lists/Documents/Items/1`

In both cases, the item ID is 1.

Does that help?

Comment: I should have specified. this is the `ItemID`. I'm looking for something unique. It appears that MS graph api has a unique ID form, as talked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011662/getting-a-sharepoint-listitem-using-guid-in-graph-api and in that example it was "01JSWLMSD5CVNHFLHNDNGLWP2WGNNGDEG2"

Comment: I think you can still get the response you want using the list item ID. Just append `driveItem` to the Graph request I included in my answer.

Comment: It's the third HTTP request option from the bottom https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request